# The following _TypeError was thrown building TestClass(dirty, dependencies:

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to filter food items based on their category but keep getting the below error.
The idea is to manually pass a String for the category of my choice using the Provider package and then filter and print the items that match the category from the list that has the food items.

```
 I/flutter ( 7404): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 7404): The following _TypeError was thrown building TestClass(dirty, dependencies:
I/flutter ( 7404): [_InheritedProviderScope<DummyData>]):
I/flutter ( 7404): type 'WhereIterable<Products>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Products>'
```

Here is the snippet of the dummy data where I have the categories and food items defined in the lists named categories and products respectively. I'm pretty confident that the filter at the end is not very well defined.

```
    class DummyData with ChangeNotifier {

  List<Categories> categories = [
    Categories(
        catId: '1',
        title: 'American',
        imageUrl: 'https://www.recipetineats.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Beef-Hamburgers_7-2.jpg?w=500&h=500&crop=1'
    ),
    Categories(
        catId: '2',
        title: 'North Indian',
        imageUrl: 'https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/53205522.cms?width=1200&height=1200'
    ),
    Categories(
        catId: '3',
        title: 'Chinese',
        imageUrl: 'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5c481361c604e53624138c2f/5c6cd55ca1bcb14248ded5c4_chilli-pork-website-thumbnail-.png'
    ),
  ];

  List<Products> products = [
    
    Products(
        id: '1',
        name: 'Mac & Cheese',
        preparationTime: '30 mins',
        imageUrl: 'https://www.inspiredtaste.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Easy-Creamy-Stovetop-Mac-and-Cheese-1200.jpg',
        category: 'American'
    ),
    Products(
        id: '2',
        name: 'Hamburger',
        preparationTime: '30 mins',
        imageUrl: 'https://www.recipetineats.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Beef-Hamburgers_7-2.jpg?w=500&h=500&crop=1',
        category: 'American'
    ),
    Products(
        id: '3',
        name: 'Chilli Pork',
        preparationTime: '1 Hr',
        imageUrl: 'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5c481361c604e53624138c2f/5c6cd55ca1bcb14248ded5c4_chilli-pork-website-thumbnail-.png',
        category: 'Chinese'
    ),
    Products(
        id: '4',
        name: 'Fried Rice',
        preparationTime: '15 mins',
        imageUrl: 'https://www.saveur.com/resizer/lijLVB5tWYhp-81mavFmDDxy_Xo=/600x600/arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-bonnier.s3.amazonaws.com/public/SITSUSMWR7A2IQ64GMSPSIOOQE.jpg',
        category: 'Chinese'
    ),
    Products(
        id: '4',
        name: 'Butter Chicken',
        preparationTime: '1 Hr',
        imageUrl: 'https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/53205522.cms?width=1200&height=1200',
        category: 'North Indian'
    ),
    Products(
        id: '5',
        name: 'Chicken Tikka Masala',
        preparationTime: '1 Hr',
        imageUrl: 'https://i2.wp.com/spicecravings.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Palak-Paneer-5-500x500.jpg',
        category: 'North Indian'
    ),
  List<Categories> get categoryType {
    return [...categories];
  }

  List<Products> get food {
    return[...products];
  }

  List<Products> filter(String title) {
    return products.where((element) => element.category == title);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read this: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, where specifically does the behavior of the code and runtime variable values differ from what you expect?

Comment: the variable str only shows the first word and the for loop does not iterate any further after having extracted the first string.I reckon that's where the problem lies.Do you think you can help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is already answered. But instead of walking through the characters of the string it is better to use the standard Java library as follows:

```
name = in.readLine();
if (name != null && !"".equals(name)) {
    String[] arr = name.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

The `split()` method does what you're trying to program yourself. 
The string `\\s+` ist a regular expression which represents one or more space characters (space, newline, ...). You could also use `" "` instead, but in this case your input must contain only one space character.

Example:

> System.out.println("Enter Name");

Input:

```
firstname secondname         lastname
```

> output:

```
firstname
secondname
lastname
```

Comment: Thanks a ton but could you also point out where i'm going wrong in my code if that's ok with you???

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, the code seems ok. But the problem is when you reach the end of the input. In that point you have reached the point where `<last_position> = names.length()`. Because this `<last_position>` is _not less than_ `names.length()` you leave the loop before you assign the last word. So, you could add `str` after the loop as: `if (str != null && !"".equals(str)) arr[k] = str;`.

Answer (score 0):

When you first loop finishes you have last word in `str` variable.

You need t o add `arr[k++] = str;` after loop to put it into array.

Comment: Yes. Right before ` for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)`.